# from discord.ext.commands import CommandNotFound problem

Tags: python, discord

I've got a problem with my music bot
It shows the same error again and again. Everytime when I type ?join or something like that (a command) it shows this message:  Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.command.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "(the command I've used)" is not found
Can someone help pls?

Code:
`main.py`:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music
import os
import requests
import json


token = os.environ['botpw']

cogs = [music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents = discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
  cogs[i].setup(client)
  


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


client.run(token)
```

music.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

@commands.command()
async def join(self,ctx):
  if ctx.author.voice is None:
    await ctx.send("Du bist nicht in einem Channel")
  voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
  if ctx.voice_client is None:
    await voice_channel.connect()
  else:
    await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

@commands.command()
async def disconnect(self,ctx):
  await ctx.voice_client.disconnect

@commands.command()
async def play(self,ctx,url):
  ctx.voice_client.stop()
  FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
    'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_steamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'
  }
  YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':'bestaudio'}
  vc = ctx.voice_client

  with youtube_dl.Youtube_dl(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
    source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
    vc.play(source)


@commands.command()
async def pause(self, ctx):
  await ctx.voice_client.pause
  await ctx.send('pausiert ')


  
@commands.command()
async def resume(self, ctx):
  await ctx.voice_client.resume
  await ctx.send('play ')



def setup (client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your indents are same as you pasted here. The problem is here.

`play`, `pause`, etc are separated functions but not `music` class methods.

You should [add indents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html) to it:

```
class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

→→@commands.command()
→→async def join(self,ctx):
→→→→...

  ...

  @commands.command()
  async def pause(self, ctx):
    ...
  @commands.command()
  async def resume(self, ctx):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you bro. You saved me hours.